# is there any way in Mailchimp/mandrill transactional API php to track not opened emails since specifc time

Tags: php, api, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I am using [Mailchimp transaction PHP API - Mandrill](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-transactional-php) for sending emails to users. I want to know the status of the outgoing emails and whether the user has opened the email in the past 1 month, 3 months etc, I tried to find any way in the API documentation, checked webhooks etc but didn't find any way/method in Mailchimp transactional PHP API to achieve this. I want to remove those users in our system who are not active and have not opened the email.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _"I tried to find any way in the API documentation"_ - the actual API documentation? Or just the documentation of the library you referred to?

Comment: @CBroe the documentation I referred